# Dynamic Columns in Grid in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have some store, which is formed data. On panel it looks how "fieldName" and text field (in depension from invoked form). For example, on one form is displayed "name document" and field, on another: date of selling and date field. Data is formed dynamicly

Here is store:

```
tableTempStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    url: objectUrlAddress,
    baseParams: {
        'objectID': objectID
    },
    root: 'Fields',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Type',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'Value'
    }, {
        name: 'IsRequired',
        type: 'bool'
    }, {
        name: 'Identifier'
    }, {
        name: 'Data'
    }],
    listeners: {
        load: function(obj, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function(rec) {

                var item = null;
                switch (rec.get('Type')) {
                    case 0:
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        item = new Ext.form.NumberField();
                        item.id = rec.get('Identifier');
                        item.fieldLabel = rec.get('Hint');
                        var isRequired = rec.get('IsRequired');
                        item.anchor = '100%';
                        item.allowBlank = !isRequired;
                        item.allowDecimals = true;
                        item.disabled = editDisabled;
                        item.value = rec.get('Data');
                        break;
                }
                if (item != null) {
                    grid.add(item);
                    tableValue = Ext.getCmp('propGrid').doLayout();
                    source[item.fieldLabel] = tableValue;
                    //grid.doLayout();
                }
            });
            grid.setSource(source);
        }
    }
});
```

This code had worked in a form, but I need to use Grid (or Editor Grid). I know, how displayed field name ("document name" and etc.), but I don't understand, how displayed text field or etc. For form I had used doLayout. How can I do this?

Here is Grid:

```
var templateGrids = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    id: 'tableId',
    height:300,
    width: '100%',
    clicksToEdit:1,
    frame: true,
    store: tableTempStore,
    columns: [
    {header: 'Value' dataIndex: typeValue}, 
    {header: 'Name' dataIndex: ''}]
    })
```

Please, help me! Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reproduce this at http://fiddle.sencha.com ? Since it's a somewhat complex problem, it would be much easier for others to investigate